# Export html table to Excel that works in IE

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html-table, export-to-excel

I'm looking for a way to export a table to Excel. I found some codes online but either some of them don't work on internet explorer and the ones that do work on IE requires me to change Active X setting in IE. I need a solution that will work in IE without the need to change Active X Control. Help!  My table is displayed in a JSP page and the Table is populated from database. I'm using spring Framework.

Comment: So what have you tried? OR do you want someone to develop that software for you?

Comment: No I dont need anyone to develop it for me I just needed some advice. However, dataTables Api TableTools Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatables tabletools api.

http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/